# Tab cursor when character inputed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is a JS fiddle example:

http://jsfiddle.net/t3u8q5vr/1/

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" maxlength="1" size="1" />
<input type="text" maxlength="1" size="1" />
<input type="text" maxlength="1" value="e" tabindex="-1" size="1" readonly />
<input type="text" maxlength="1" size="1" />
<input type="text" maxlength="1" value="r" tabindex="-1" size="1" readonly />
<input type="text" maxlength="1" size="1" />

<div>
<button class="buttons">á</button>
<button class="buttons">é</button>
<button class="buttons">í</button>
<button class="buttons">ó</button>
<button class="buttons">ú</button>
<button class="buttons">ñ</button>
<button class="buttons">ü</button>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$("input").bind("input", function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.val().length >= parseInt($this.attr("maxlength"), 10)) {
        var nextEmpty = $this.nextAll("input[value=''], input:not([value])")[0];
        if (nextEmpty) {
            nextEmpty.focus();
        }
    }
});

$('input').focus(function(){
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings('.active').removeClass('active')
});

$(".buttons").click(function () {
    var cntrl = $(this).html();
    $('input.active').val(cntrl);
    var $curInputNode = $('input.active');

    while($curInputNode.is('input:text') && $curInputNode.val() != ''){
        $curInputNode = $curInputNode.next();
    }
    $curInputNode.focus();
});
```

The above JSFiddle I've been working on has the desired behavior I want to apply to my website (it auto tabs when a character is inserted via keyboard or via clicking one of the buttons to insert text).

When I apply this code to my website though, a single button click (for example á) inserts two of the á characters:

[image: example issue]

Any thoughts on why this is occuring?

Comment: Seems to be working on the fiddle. what's the difference between the fiddle and your site? Also, what OS/browser are you using? (I tried Win7/Chrome (latest)

Comment: I'm using Chrome. I can't quite figure out what the difference would be between the two. A single button click seems to call the function twice though.

Comment: you could try changing `$(".buttons").click(function () {` to `$(".buttons").on('click', function () {`

Comment: same issue, thanks for the input though---OS is ubuntu 12.04 LTS